# Error in adding django-axes to project

Tags: python, django, web, authentication, axes

I have **installed django axes** with this command in **cmd** :

```
pip install django-axes
```

Then i addes to my setting.py file this parts :

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'post_app',
    'axes',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'axes.middleware.FailedLoginMiddleware',
]

AXES_LOCK_OUT_AT_FAILURE = False
AXES_USE_USER_AGENT = True
AXES_COOLOFF_TIME = 1
AXES_LOGIN_FAILURE_LIMIT = 50
```

Now i want to runserver with this command :

```
python manage.py runserver
```

But i **have this error in cmd** :

```
  Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x0000000004AA4908>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\data\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\python\data\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "D:\python\data\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 251, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "D:\python\data\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\python\data\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "D:\python\data\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "D:\python\data\lib\site-packages\axes\apps.py", line 9, in ready
    from axes.decorators import watch_login
  File "D:\python\data\lib\site-packages\axes\decorators.py", line 3, in <module>
    from socket import inet_pton, AF_INET6, error
ImportError: cannot import name inet_pton
```

Is there any mistake?or any missed work?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run python manage.py migrate to sync the database before you run the server? If you did, then you need to check your python version and django verison, check this for detail:https://github.com/jazzband/django-axes/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: Then what's your python version and django version?

Comment: python 2.7 django 1.11

Comment: Which operation system you are using? windows?

Comment: windows 10 64 bit

Comment: OK, check this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.inet_pton, it works on Unix not other OS.

Comment: The error you got is about can't import name inet_pton in socket package, and the link shows that socket.inet_pton function only be available in Unix environment and maybe not other platforms. So you either use VM to create a Unix-like env or switch to another alternative library.